# How could i make a line break in a text field in android

Tags: android, text, lines

I would like to know how to make a line break like this in a String:

This text goes on for..
... ever

could there be a next line method?

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding `\n` (the line break character) to the text, that should make a new line

```
"Text text\nNext Line Text"
```